# 552 5.3.4 Error: message file too big

Tags: java, jenkins, smtp, jakarta-mail, filesize

I have created a .bat file **i.e. launchMonthlyreport.bat** to launch monthly report (**2 excel files**) email sending using **JavaMail** in my application.

**launchMonthlyreport.bat**

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -Dlog4j.configuration="..\\conf\\log4j_batch_sendmailmonthlyreport.xml" -jar "X.jar" BATCH_REPORT_FR
```

**NOTE**: Its working properly by manually running the **launchMonthlyreport.bat** file on the server.
i.e **No JavaMail error (message file too big)**

But I need to run the bat file periodically i.e **monthly**.
So I'm using **JENKINS** to run the launchMonthlyreport.bat periodically using the cron job

[image]

But I'm getting the following error while trying to build the job

**ERROR:**

```
D:\PROJ\TEST_FOLDER\test>java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -Dlog4j.configuration="..\\conf\\log4j_batch_sendmailmonthlyreport.xml" -jar "X.jar" BATCH_REPORT_FR
    INFO - Start for batch type = BATCH_REPORT_FR
    INFO - [MONTHLY_BATCH_REPORT_FR]-[EXECUTE_REPORTS] Report for A attached
    INFO - [MONTHLY_BATCH_REPORT_FR]-[EXECUTE_REPORTS] Report for B attached
    INFO - [MAIL] - [SENDER] Sender email address: XYZ@gmail.com
    INFO - [MAIL] - [RECIPIENT] Recipient email address: xyz@gmail.com
    ERROR - sentMail Error 
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 552 5.3.4 Error: message file too big
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1862)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1100)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at com.lib.service.tool.impl.MailServiceImpl.sentMail(MailServiceImpl.java:39)
        at com.batch.general.BatchReportFR.executeReports(BatchReportFR.java:107)
        at com.batch.general.BatchReportFR.run(BatchReportFR.java:57)
        at com.batch.general.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:16)
```

**It's giving problem only through running through jenkins.**

I think that server is telling that the message is too big. If yes, what configuration I need to add to increase the size limit ?

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Your error message is coming from the SMTP server (not the Java code).

Comment: Right, you need to reconfigure your SMTP server.  If it's not a server you own, you need to use a different server or just send smaller files.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. 
But the same thing is working without using jenkins (manually running the .bat file). Is it possible to add any configuration in SMTP server or may be in jenkins i need to configure something ?

Comment: *Is it possible to add any configuration in SMTP server* That **is** the correct place to look; the answer is ***probably***. Talk to your *email server administrators* about increasing the maximum outgoing email size.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : Thanks